# VideoPlayer done button: not returning to subview

Tags: ios, subviews

In a ViewController's view's subview (UIView) which contains a UIWebView, I show a YouTube video. (to be clear: ViewController.view > subview > uiwebview)

When pressing the "done" button in the video's player (full screen) I get taken back to ViewController.view. This should be ViewController.view > subview.

I read somewhere that the done button takes the user back to the root view (I have no clue why, but ok) so I implemented an observer for UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification.

That observer's selector get's fired and in that method I have tried several things:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:subview];

[subview.layer setZindex:100];

[subview removefromsuperview]; [self.view addSubview:subview];
```

The subview's instance is actually in self.view.subviews. And it's the same instance as well. The subview is never nil.

Suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: remove this  `[self.view addSubview:subview];` from last and try

Comment: I have tried those three lines seperately